# How to use graph database for reputation diffusion?

Tags: neo4j, orientdb, graph-databases, tinkerpop, blazegraph

I have a problem which seems to be a good fit for a graph database, but I'm uncertain of the best way to apply it.

First there is a set of objects which can have directional links (a few tens of millions of them, the typical link in/out number is a few thousand per object).  Then, each object can accumulate reputation (think upvotes, karma, etc) from a potentially very large number of users (also tens of millions).

The tricky part is that whenever a user adjusts the reputation of an object, I would like to update the reputation of all its linked objects (possibly beyond first degree) based on some fairly complicated rules.

In SQL, this would look something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE objects (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY);
CREATE TABLE object_links (from_object_id INTEGER, to_object_id INTEGER);
CREATE TABLE users (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY);
CREATE TABLE object_reputations (object_id INTEGER, user_id INTEGER, reputation FLOAT);

UPDATE
    object_reputations
SET
    object_reputations.reputation = object_reputations.reputation + ... # some formula goes here
FROM
    object_reputations
    INNER JOIN object_links
        ON object_reputations.object_id = object_links.to_object_id
WHERE
    object_links.from_object_id = ...;
```

Since this is dealing with a graph, a graph database would seem to be a natural fit, but from a quick read of the Neo4j / OrientDB / Blazegraph / Tinkerpop APIs, I can't figure out how to map this problem onto what they can do at all.

Using Tinkerpop as an example, the objects are Vertexes, the links between objects are Edges (all good so far) and the reputations are...?  Possibly VertexPropetries, but I'm not at sure how things would scale with potentially as many properties per vertex as there are users.  Or possibly the reputations are weighted edges from user-Vertexes... that would seem to have a different kind of performance problems.

Can you give a simple translation of this kind of problem into one of the popular graph databases?

Comment: In your SQL example, it looks a bit like each object has a "reputation" per user. Is the "reputation" not the same for all users? Could you please better clarify the meaning of what object_reputations is doing in your model?

Comment: @stephenmallette Correct, every object has a different reputation for every user.   Not all objects would in practice (it depends on how far reputation diffuses along the graph) but maybe 10% of all objects would have reputation for one particular user.

Answer (score 2):

I'd say that it really depends on how want to query your data. Reputation can also be a vertex if it has finite number of values and the values repeat across users. For example if it's a number from 1-10, then we can have all users who have a reputation of 7 link to this vertex. This model will allow you to start your query from the vertex and easily find all users that have that reputation. Using Gremlin, it'll be something like this.

```
g.V().has(label,"reputation").has("reputation","7").in()
```

That would return all vertexes that are linked to the reputation vertex with a reputation of "7".

Alternatively you can have the reputation as a property as well and you can look for all vertexes with such property.

```
g.V().has("reputation","7")
```

Number of properties shouldn't be an issue. Titan recommends you index the properties you want to query which improve the lookups quite a bit

Comment: Upvoted because I agree with the simplicity of the structure. The only point I would make is that I don't think you should make the reputation a property on every vertex. Rather you should have specific reputation vertices (like you do so in the first part of this answer). The reason for this is that the question specifies that the reputations need to be mutated and it's much easier (at large scale) to modify edges to vertices rather to mutate vertices themselves.

Answer (score 1):

You want to always try to visualize graph data queries without using any big tables (basically, anything more than 2 or 3 properties per vertex should be used almost exclusively for data storage, not querying). If you can't change such complex data to be represented by a longer path between vertices, then it probably belongs in a relational database.

For 'perspective' based data like yours, though, a graph database is a good fit. Instead of storing all of the User-oriented reputations as properties on the Object, though, move them onto separate nodes attached to the object, so that they can be turned into part of the path from User to Object.

So, you have a vertex for the User, a vertex for the Object, and each has an edge to a third vertex, the ObjectReputation. Each Object will have several adjacent ObjectReputation vertices (one for each User related to the Object), but there is only a single path along edges from any User to any Object. To find related ObjectReputations, you can navigate along edges from the User to the Object, navigate along edges between Objects, then navigate back from those Objects through UserReputation vertices to the original User.

In `neo4j`'s Cypher query language, it would look something like this:

```
MERGE (u:User {id:1})
MERGE (o:Object {id:2})
MERGE (u) - [:KNOWS] -> (ur:ObjectReputation) - [:KNOWS] -> (o)
SET ur.score = 100
MATCH (o) - [:RELATED_TO*] - (:Object) <- [:KNOWS] - (related_ur:ObjectReputation) <- [:KNOWS] - (u)
SET related_ur.score = related_ur.score * 1.2
```